# Ad Pop Up when my website loads

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When my website loads for the first time, an unknown Ad pop up will displayed and FYI i didn't use any IFRAME. So what might be the problem and how to block that advertisement pop up?
Thanks in advance

Comment: cross site scripting attack ????

Comment: i'm not sure..but if that's the case then how to fix..? @Ganesh_Devlekar

Comment: @paven [building a content security policy](https://report-uri.io/home/generate) can help protect your site from browsers loading malicious scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Chrome's Inspect tools (or edge or ff, whatever browser) to see what's loading from where. Select the Network tab and refresh your site. From there you should be able to see where the pop-up is coming from and start looking through your site from the problem.

I can only speculate as to what kind of site you're running, but if you have a database that stores content entered by users, then check there first (comments etc).

There are quite a few other ways this could happen.

- Your site is hosted on a "free" server which injects adds into your website
- Your ftp password has been compromised and the actual content of your site has been altered
- You're loading scripts from an external source and they've been compromised (or are just malicious)

Either way - the inspect tools will tell you where it's coming from, then you'll have the job of tracking it down! Remember you can place breakpoints in javascript in the "Source" tab of the inspect tools, so you can run scripts one line at a time. Might help track it down...